# Two UINavigationControllers after using NavigationLink in sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a modal sheet that is presented from my home view as such:

```
    Button(action: {
        ...
    }) {
        ...
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: ...) {
        MySheetView()
    }
```

In `MySheetView`, there is a `NavigationView` and a `NavigationLink` to push another view onto its view stack (while I'm on `MySheetView` screen and use the view inspector, there's only one `UINavigationController` associated with it which is what I expect).

However, as soon as I get to my next view that is presented from `MySheetView` using the `NavigationLink`, and I use the view hierarchy debugger, there are **TWO** `UINavigationControllers` on-top of each other. Note, this view does NOT have a `NavigationView` inside it, only `MySheetView` does.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I have a feeling this is causing some navigation bugs im experiencing. This can be easily reproduced in an example app with the same structure.

Ex:

```
// These are 3 separate SwiftUI files
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: { self.isPresented = true }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { 
                ModalView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: FinalView()) {
                Text("Go to final")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FinalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't observe the behaviour you described. Used Xcode 11.2. Probably you need to provide your code to find the reason.

[image: navigationview in sheet]

Here is an example of using navigation views in main screen and sheet. (*Note*: removing navigation view in main screen does not affect one in sheet).

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestNavigationInSheet: View {
    @State private var hasSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {self.hasSheet = true }) {
                Text("Show it")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main")
            .sheet(isPresented: $hasSheet) { self.sheetContent }
        }
    }

    private var sheetContent: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Properties")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Sheet")
                NavigationLink(destination: properties) {
                    Text("Go to Inspector")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var properties: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Inspector")
        }
    }
}

struct TestNavigationInSheet_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestNavigationInSheet()
    }
}
```

Comment: I uploaded my example project where I can replicate the same issue. In `FinalView` I see two `UINavigationControllers`

Comment: Your screenshot looks right, but open the `Debug View Hierarchy` button while running the app on a simulator while on your `properties` view. You should see two `UINavigationControllers`

Comment: hm.. the code is the same... I see only .. well I attached screenshot. And what do you mean by *UINavigationControllers*, and how do you recognise that there are two of them?

Comment: See above comment

Comment: Ahaa... ok... that's different question... what and how Apple renders SwiftUI...

Comment: Yeah, this was my question. It seems odd there are two UINavigationControllers ontop of eachother. I get a lot of weird behavior with NavigationLinks chained together and was trying to figure out the causes. Thought this looked weird